Is there a way to replace a value with another from table in query mysql
I have a company table with the following fields - id, year, dept, amt. I need the query the table such that the amount is grouped by id and year:

my desired output:

I need the sum of amount grouped by id and year, but the dept should only choose the value other than B
I did:
select id, year, dept, sum(amt)
from Table a
Where dept in ('A', 'B')
group by id, year

The issue is that it does the sum of the amount grouped by year but it pull the dept value as B in certain cases.
I want the code not to return dept B but the other dept associated with that id and year

If the dept should not include B, why are you explicitly saying that dept can be A or B in your where statement?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Look at their desired sums. They want the summation to include B, but not the output.

Change dept in the select list to MIN(dept). That will select A if it exists in the group, otherwise B.

Why are you including dept in the output if it's not the only department that's included in the sum?

What should it return if the id/year only has dept=B?

if you don't want to include 'dept' B then use condition:
Where dept not in ('B')

Also you want to grouped by id and year, then why you show the dept name in your desire output. Because your sum(amt) will come from different department other than dept: B. So, you cann't show the dept name there.
I think your query should be:
select id, year, sum(amt)
from company
Where dept not in ('B')
group by id, year;

Check db<>fiddle sample code: https://dbfiddle.uk/pWhX4xI2

